# How do I style the background color of alternating table rows?

Tags: html, css

I was was just wondering how to get this kind of design done when things are fetched dynamically? I mean there has to be only one class which can be used to get the background colour depending upon whether block is odd or even. I hope my requirements are clear: background color varying with the odd or even number for the rows.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery/JavaScript? if not, what language is generating it?

Comment: looks like you should have tagged it a javascript problem. Maybe you can do something similar with CSS only creating a background  image with a white part and a grey one, and having it repeat vertically.

Comment: this is getting fetched using  php ...

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for alternating rows. This is accomplishable by adding a different class to every other row.

[Tutorials are plenty](http://www.google.ca/search?q=alternating+rows+style) on how to do this.

[CSS3 also provides a new way to do this](http://davidwalsh.name/css-tables-css3-alternate-row-colors) without adding classes:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)   { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've not specified a language for what's returning the code I'll give you a pure CSS answer.

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {YOURSTYLEINHERE}
or
tr:nth-child(odd) {YOURSTYLEINHERE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a second css class for the alternating row. Assuming that the default bg color here is dark gray, the second class would look like this:

.altRow
{
     background-color:white !important;
}

If you don't want to have to code the logic server-side for applying the second class, you can use JQuery's [Odd selector](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/). But that's about as close are you're going to get to zebra-striping without just manually applying a second class.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is modulus division

```
if(rowNum % 2 == 0) {class="even"} else {class="odd"}
```

OR if you are using CSS3 you can do it like this

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: bt nth child wont work i ie ?? any way to do that without javascript??