# How do I alternate the background color in a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, alternate

I want an alternate background colors inside of a div. Which I have done through this code below:

I want my first row to be present with a bgcolor and the next row with an alternate color.

I tried but it didn't work.   Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".rowBg div:odd").addClass("altBg");
    });
</script>

/*CSS*/
div.rowBg div { clear:both; padding:0; overflow:hidden }
div.altBg {  background-color:#eee !important;  overflow:hidden; padding:5px 0 } 
<!--HTML-->
<div class="rowBg">
            <div>
            <!--Row1-->
            <span class="alphabets">A</span>
            <span class="itemNames">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294963558">Acer America</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3703">Acronis</a></li>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294966145">Adaptec</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3163">Adobe</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=4402">AirWatch</a></li>
            </ul>           
            </span>
            </div>
            <!--Row 2-->
            <div>
            <!--Row1-->
            <span class="alphabets">A</span>
            <span class="itemNames">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294963558">Acer America</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3703">Acronis</a></li>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294966145">Adaptec</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3163">Adobe</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=4402">AirWatch</a></li>

            </ul>           
            </span>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe CSS :odd and :even can do this

Comment: I sure there must be CSS . Can u paste that too?

Comment: @TCHdvlp: you're thinking of `:nth-child(odd)`/`:nth-child(even)`. I'm not aware of `:odd`/`:even` pseudo-classes.

Comment: I think :even/:odd are built into jQuery specially http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Comment: Explained in another stackoverflow post [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760034/how-do-i-style-the-background-color-of-alternating-table-rows

Comment: Your code works in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gGqfC/1/ using chrome

Comment: Ho, @David Thomas, you are right, I must have been confusing with JQuery :odd and :even, my bad.

Comment: @VIKASHATWAL I am using FF and your code seems to be working fine (although i would prefer doing it with CSS like David Thomas has mentioned). Seems to be working in IE10 too.

Comment: Perhaps Vikas must consider browser compatibility.

Comment: Vikas you  need to be a bit more specific. DO you consider each line as a ROW? Because in your code you specify each DIV as a row

Comment: @VIKASHATWAL what browser are you using? Works in chrome, ff, but ie can't load jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/kxPyM/1/. Press F12 to open debugger and look at console it may just be a simple error.

Comment: Working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SGtj5/1/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the HTML/jquery which you have posted and it is doing what you are expecting.
Each odd Div has a class of altBG.

What I would suggest is that your CSS is wrong but as that has not been posted, I can't confirm that.
if you change this line of your jquery from:

```
$(".rowBg div:odd").addClass("altBg");
```

to

```
$(".rowBg div:odd").css({"background-color":"#ff0000"})
```

you should be able to see that your markup and jquery is ok.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I can see that you have added your css now. So 
`div.rowBg div.altBg {background-color:#eee}` should be specific enough for you to force the new style.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have added jquery library? because your HTML, CSS and jQuery code is fine but you need to add library and your code will work fine.
you can download jQuery library from here  [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
<style type="text/css">
div.rowBg div { clear:both; padding:0; overflow:hidden }
div.altBg {  background-color:#eee !important;  overflow:hidden; padding:5px 0 } 
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".rowBg div:odd").addClass("altBg");
    });
</script>

<div class="rowBg">
            <div>
            <!--Row1-->
            <span class="alphabets">A</span>
            <span class="itemNames">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294963558">Acer America</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3703">Acronis</a></li>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294966145">Adaptec</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3163">Adobe</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=4402">AirWatch</a></li>
            </ul>           
            </span>
            </div>
            <!--Row 2-->
            <div>
            <!--Row1-->
            <span class="alphabets">A</span>
            <span class="itemNames">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294963558">Acer America</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3703">Acronis</a></li>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294966145">Adaptec</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3163">Adobe</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=4402">AirWatch</a></li>

            </ul>           
            </span>
            </div>
<div>
            <!--Row1-->
            <span class="alphabets">A</span>
            <span class="itemNames">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294963558">Acer America</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3703">Acronis</a></li>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294966145">Adaptec</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3163">Adobe</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=4402">AirWatch</a></li>
            </ul>           
            </span>
            </div>
<div>
            <!--Row1-->
            <span class="alphabets">A</span>
            <span class="itemNames">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294963558">Acer America</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3703">Acronis</a></li>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294966145">Adaptec</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3163">Adobe</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=4402">AirWatch</a></li>
            </ul>           
            </span>
            </div>
<div>
            <!--Row1-->
            <span class="alphabets">A</span>
            <span class="itemNames">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294963558">Acer America</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3703">Acronis</a></li>
            <li><a href="../locate/refine.html?N=4294966145">Adaptec</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=3163">Adobe</a></li>
            <li><a href="../promotions/index.html?page_id=4402">AirWatch</a></li>
            </ul>           
            </span>
            </div>

            </div>
```